# How to change only portion of text foreground color in gtk.Entry (or gtk.TextView)?

Tags: colors, gtk, foreground

I can change the whole foreground color of a gtk.Entry text by using modify_text function, but my problem is to change the color of only a portion of it.
Suppose my widget text is: "Hello World", my goal is to change the color of first 5 character to blue ("Hello" word) and left remaining text unchanged.

Comment: I think it's impossible as of now. One option would be to look into GtkSourceView but that sounds overkill.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [C example here](http://www.gtkforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=1189) demonstrating this sort of coloration within a TextView widget.  I donno if you wanted a C example or another language, but the TexView widget supports it.

Also, that example might just build under Linux but [GTK always needs `pkg-config` under MacPorts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24474928/gtk-hello-world-not-working-on-osx) :

```
gcc -o gtk_textview_color_test gtk_textview_color_test.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`
```