# GTK hello world not working on OSX

Tags: macos, gtk

I am just starting to work with GTK and want to create cross-platform apps. I've worked through some tutorials and copied the example at https://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/stable/c39.html#SEC-HELLOWORLD, compiled it with `gcc -o gtkTest gtkTest.c 'pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0'` but when I went to run it, I got:

```
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _cairo_xlib_surface_create
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgdk-3.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libcairo.2.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _cairo_xlib_surface_create
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libgdk-3.0.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/local/lib/libcairo.2.dylib
```

I'm not sure what this means (my programming abilities are limited) - any ideas??
Thanks,
Ed

Comment: You are using a GTK+ 2.0 tutorial with GTK+ 3.0 so should expect some problems... but the one you're seeing is not related to that: it probably means your system is not set up correctly: I would guess X and/or Cairo installs are not what they should be?

Comment: @jku thanks! I think I've dug myself a bit of a hole by installing various things in all sorts of combinations... what's the easiest way to start from scratch? Is there anything I can do to "reset" the system and have an install of GTK that will work easily?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough experience with OS X to comment.

Answer (score 1):

If this isn't a typo, you must have backticks (`) and not single quotes (').

Commands under backticks are executed, but commands under single quotes aren't.

So you have:

```
    gcc -o gtkTest gtkTest.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

If this isn't the problem, try reinstalling GTK.

**UPDATE:**

Try to reinstall Cairo, because when you link with gtk+-3.0, you link with Cairo.
This is a GTK+ 2 tutorial, for GTK+ 3 follow [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-getting-started.html) tutorial.

**UPDATE 2:**

Did you install GTK to the standard path? /usr/local/include for includes, or whatever it is on OSX? If you did not, you must enter this to bash:

```
    gcc -o gtkTest gtkTest.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -L/whatever/library/path -I/whatever/include/path
```

Replace /whatever/includeorlib/path with your include and library path.
-L is to set the library path and -I is for include path.

BASH IS CASE-SENSITIVE.

**NOTE:**

I use Linux, so this might not work. I suppose that this works on OSX too because Linux and OSX are Unix-like systems.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was using backticks - I changed them to quotes to show the code as code here (how can I escape them)? When I ran gcc -o gtkTest gtkTest.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` with the GTK+3 example I got a `gtkTest.c:1:10: fatal error: 'gtk/gtk.h' file not found
#include <gtk/gtk.h>` When I added the paths: `gcc -o gtkTest gtkTest.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -L/usr/local/lib/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/local/include/gtk-3.0` the error changed to `/usr/local/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h:13:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not
      found
#include <glib.h>` ???

Comment: Try to `ls /usr/local/include/gtk-3.0` and all its subdirectories to see does glib.h exist or is it corrupted. If it is OK, then try reinstalling GTK in a different directory, like `~/include` and `~/lib` and put that in your include and lib path. If that doesn't work, try building with Clang. This is your default compiler for XCode (I suppose you have OS X Mavericks). Call it from bash with the same options. I recommend you to use Clang, because I use it on Ubuntu and it's great. By the way, \`backticks\` are made with escape sequences. \ and a backtick.

Comment: The only glib.h file is in `/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/include/glib-2.0` and seems to be fine. I haven't used Clang but have used brew and macports. I'll look up Clang...

Comment: Try to edit the include directive on the 13th line in /usr/local/include/gtk-3.0/gdk/gdkconfig.h so it matches the absolute path of glib.h (`#include "/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.40.0_1/include/glib-2.0/glib.h"`).

Comment: When you use gcc on recent Mac systems, it actually uses Clang instead. Try running it with no arguments—it'll print `clang: error: no input files`!